# android host txt file and read it

Tags: java, android, dropbox, onedrive

I doing a application with a database, and to check if I need update the database I want to read a txt file and check the version. The problem is I cant find any website to store my txt file and edit. I tried to use onedrive, dropbox, etc but the link to the file doesnt finish with `.txt` so instead of read the file I read the html code. Somebody know any website to store and edit my txt file? Or somebody know how I can read the file from onedrive or dropbox? Where is my code to read the txt file:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        System.out.println("starting");
        try {

            URL url = new URL("");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;

            str = in.readLine();

            in.close();

            System.out.println("version: " + str);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks for the help and sorry my english.

Comment: Sorry I edited my tittle, was wrong.

Comment: Azazel why don't you put the file in app only?And why only txt?

Comment: @AndroidLearner because he wants to check whether the app needs to update the database or not from the text file. So he will be updating the version number in the text file. In a local file it won't be possible to update the text file when a new version is available.

Comment: The txt file have the most recent version of the database, when the app starts I read the txt file and I update the database if necessary. So instead of update the application in the store I just need update the txt file and the database.

Comment: You can use parse.com too to save some data like version number. It comes with an sdk too so it would be very easy for you to add it to your project.

Comment: @GauravVashisth thanks for the tip, but I prefer read a simply txt file.

Comment: If you do want to use a Dropbox shared link ( https://www.dropbox.com/help/167 ) you'll need to modify it for direct file access: https://www.dropbox.com/help/201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take so many time and its a simple soluction for the onedrive, just need to copy the download link of the file and can read fine.